# how to search in 2D char array for the same fields?(of five in line game) in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to C and programming and I've got a problem with my homework.
All of zou know game called "of five in line". My work is to create a program, which evalute players's position after each move. It has to say which line is the longest (in vertical, horizontal and both diagonal ways) and also print how many lines like that are in the field.
So the input is the position and output should look like this: Player 'X' has the longest line of 3 (3 times).
I've got a field like this:

```
#define MAX_LINE 26
#define MAX_COLUMN 26

char playField[MAX_LINE][MAX_COLUMN]
```

ane after few moves I'm in a situation like this:

```
playField[1][2]=='X'
playField[1][3]=='O'
playField[2][2]=='X'
playField[1][4]=='O'
playField[9][5]=='X'
```

so how do I search for the longest lines? This was just an example, field can have much more elements.
My idea was to do it with some cycles but it seemed impossible to write it for me.
Thanks for help

Comment: Just simple for loop with one if statement in all directions should solve your problem.

Comment: oh, would you mind specifying it more?

Comment: Please specifiy what is the expected output for the test case you presented.

Comment: Expected output is "Player 'X' has the longest line of 3 elements and this line can be found once in the given field.

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxO = 0; //max length of O's
int maxX = 0; //max length of X's


char last;     //the last player we checked (or nothing)
int  lastCount;//the last count for the "last"
```

### Check lines

```
//lines along lines
/*
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _
    _ _ X X X _ _
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _

    for each line 
        for each column
            check for longest X/0

*/
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LINE; ++i) {
    last = 0;
    lastCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMN; ++j) {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < MAX_LINE && j >= 0 && j < MAX_COLUMN);
        //check if same player
        if (last == playField[i][j]) {
            //same player
            lastCount += 1;
        } else {
            //not same player, set counted length for the right player
            if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
                //it's player O
                maxO = lastCount;
            } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
                //it's player X
                maxX = lastCount;
            }
            //update for next player (or nothing)
            lastCount = 1;
            last = playField[i][j];
        }
    }
    if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
        //it's player O
        maxO = lastCount;
    } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
        //it's player X
        maxX = lastCount;
    }
}
```

### Check columns

```
//lines along columns
/*
    _ _ _ X _ _ _
    _ _ _ X _ _ _
    _ _ _ X _ _ _

    for each column
        for each line
            check for longest X/0

*/
for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMN; ++j) {
    last = 0;
    lastCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LINE; ++i) {
        assert(i >= 0 && i < MAX_LINE && j >= 0 && j < MAX_COLUMN);
        if (last == playField[i][j]) {
            lastCount += 1;
        } else {
            if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
                maxO = lastCount;
            } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
                maxX = lastCount;
            }
            lastCount = 1;
            last = playField[i][j];
        }
    }
    if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
        //it's player O
        maxO = lastCount;
    } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
        //it's player X
        maxX = lastCount;
    }
}
```

### Check diagonals

```
//lines along diagonals
/*
    _ _ _ X _ _ _
    _ _ X _ _ _ _
    _ X _ _ _ _ _

    for each line + column
        for each column
            shift coordinates
                0 1 2 3 4 5 6
                _ _ _ X _ _ _
                _ _ X _ _ _ _
                _ X _ _ _ _ _
                to
                0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
                _ _ _ X _ _ _
                  _ _ X _ _ _ _
                    _ X _ _ _ _ _
              check if shifted coordiantes are in range
                  check for longest X/0

*/
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LINE + MAX_COLUMN - 1; ++i) {
    last = 0;
    lastCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMN; ++j) {
        int iShift = i - j;
        if (iShift >= 0 && iShift < MAX_LINE) {
            assert(iShift >= 0 && iShift < MAX_LINE && j >= 0 && j < MAX_COLUMN);
            if (last == playField[iShift][j]) {
                lastCount += 1;
            } else {
                if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
                    maxO = lastCount;

                } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
                    maxX = lastCount;
                }
                lastCount = 1;
                last = playField[iShift][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
        //it's player O
        maxO = lastCount;
    } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
        //it's player X
        maxX = lastCount;
    }
}
```

### Check diagonals 2

```
//lines along diagonals 2
/*
    _ _ _ X _ _ _
    _ _ _ _ X _ _
    _ _ _ _ _ X _

    for each line + column
        for each column
            shift coordinates
                0 1 2 3 4 5 6
                _ _ _ X _ _ _
                _ _ _ _ X _ _
                _ _ _ _ _ X _

                to
               -2-1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
                    _ _ _ X _ _ _
                  _ _ _ _ X _ _
                _ _ _ _ _ X _

              check if shifted coordiantes are in range
                  check for longest X/0

*/
for(int i = -MAX_COLUMN + 1; i < MAX_LINE; ++i) {
    last = 0;
    lastCount = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMN; ++j) {
        int iShift = i + j;            
        if (iShift >= 0 && iShift < MAX_LINE) {
            assert(iShift >= 0 && iShift < MAX_LINE && j >= 0 && j < MAX_COLUMN);
            if (last == playField[iShift][j]) {
                lastCount += 1;
            } else {
                if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
                    maxO = lastCount;
                } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
                    maxX = lastCount;
                }
                lastCount = 1;
                last = playField[iShift][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (last == 'O' && maxO < lastCount) {
        //it's player O
        maxO = lastCount;
    } else if (last  == 'X' && maxX < lastCount) {
        //it's player X
        maxX = lastCount;
    }
}
```

### Print result

```
//print result
printf("Player X longest line %d\n", maxX);
printf("Player O longest line %d\n", maxO);
```